# What does *she had spiked out stylishly* mean?

Tags: meaning

*Context: “Hi,” chirped a girl beside me. I lifted my head to look at her. She was pretty in a ‘not in your face’ kind of way, she had short black **hair with some blue streaks which she had spiked out stylishly**, and big brown eyes. She was smiling a friendly smile.*

> What does it mean? Does it fashionably or not cool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take it very literally. She had stylishly formed her hair into spikes that stood out from her head.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [something like this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_jwV39Ir8DRo/S9gb0NZfJ0I/AAAAAAAAARI/_4uOpJTkvgs/s400/s1.jpg), though whether that is "stylish" or not is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @tobyink: Snap! Actually, yours is better than the one I just cheekily shoved into your text. Delete mine or change it if you like.

Comment: Well, I`ll think about it, but thanks that explained to me what this phrase is mean.